# Minimum of two variables function $f(x,y)=x^2+3y^2+x\sqrt{3}+y\sqrt{6}+xy\sqrt{8}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the minimum value of

> $$f(x,y)=x^2+3y^2+x\sqrt{3}+y\sqrt{6}+xy\sqrt{8}$$

Using partial derivatives, \begin{align*}f_x&=2x+\sqrt{3}+y\sqrt{8} \\ f_y&=6y+\sqrt{6}+x\sqrt{8}\end{align*} Equating both equation to zero and solving we get $\displaystyle (x,y)=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0\right)$.

The determinant of hessian is $$\left|\begin{matrix}f_{xx}&f_{xy} \\ f_{yx}&f_{yy}\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}2&\sqrt{8}\\\sqrt{8}&6\end{matrix}\right|=4$$ and $f_{xx}>0$, hence the point is a minimum point.

> I wanted to know if there is other way to simplify the function and find the required value without using messy methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way to find the minimum value of such function.
We have that
$$f(x,y)=\left(x+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\sqrt{2}y\right)^2+y^2-\frac{3}{4}\geq -\frac{3}{4}=f\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0\right).$$